# flutter firebase authentication 403 (Forbidden) error occured

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I am creating my flutter login screen with firebase authentication. Actually I can successfully login and create a user as well as google and facebook social sign in.

But today, I got the following error for sing in with email, google and fb. I did not change any thing yet. May I know where do I check?

```
403. That’s an error.

Your client does not have permission to get URL /identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword from this server. That’s all we know.
```

Actual error message

```
"[firebase_auth/unknown] com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has 
occurred. [ Json conversion failed! Failed to parse error for string [<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang=en> <meta charset=utf-8> <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, 
minimum-scale=1, width=device-width"> <title>Error 403 (Forbidden)!!1</title> <style> 
*{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans- 
serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max- 
width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > 
body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no- 
repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text- 
decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px). 
{body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding- right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px} </style> <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a> <p><b>403.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins> <p>Your client does not have permission to get URL <code>/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyAssertion</code> from this server. <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>] ]"
```

login bloc

```
Future login(String email, String password) async {
emit(const AuthLoginLoading());
try {
  User? user = (await firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password))
      .user;

  // login success state
  if (user != null) {
    emit(AuthLoginSuccess(user: user));
  }
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  emit(AuthLoginError(error: e.message!));
}
}
```

Comment: Hello, any clue regarding this one? I'm facing the same